# Jquery click function to show-hide an icon in two divs at the same time

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide, closest, parents

I have a click function that I use to show or hide a 'icon (vert-flag)' when an image one is viewing in an image gallery is selected as a favorite by clicking an icon (.fav) under the image. The icon changes to indicate it is selected and the favorite (vert-flag) is shown. This works well but I am also trying to set the same favorite setting on a corresponding thumbnail image in a separate mirrored gallery at the same time and show the icon (vert-flag) there as well. My problem is figuring out how to traverse to the second gallery and mark that thumbnail at the same time.

Show-hide Click function to:

```
$(".fav").live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('sticky')
           .removeClass('icon-heart-empty')
           .addClass('icon-check')
           .toggleClass('fav')
           .closest('.selectFav')
           .toggleClass('favorites');
    $(this).closest(".selectFav").children(".vert-flag").show();
});

$(".sticky").live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fav')
           .removeClass('icon-check')
           .addClass('icon-heart-empty')
           .toggleClass('sticky')
           .closest('.selectFav')
           .toggleClass('favorites');
    $(this).closest(".selectFav").children(".vert-flag").hide();
});​
```

The html for the main image to select as a favorite:

```
<div id="book">
    <div class="selectFav" >
        <span class="vert-flag icon-heart icon-large" style="display:none;"></span>
        <h1>Wall</h1>
        <a href="slides/Wall.jpg"  title="Wall"><img  src="thumbs/Wall.jpg" alt="Wall" title="Wall"/></a>
         <div class="titles">
             <i class="fav icon-heart-empty"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

html for the corresponding thumbnail:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="item">Wall<br>
        <a href="#" title="Wall">
            <img src="thumbs/Wall.jpg"  alt="Wall" data-page="38" />
        </a>
        <span class="vert-flag icon-heart icon-large" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>
```

I have tried a few different things but I am not experienced enough to understand how to traverse the dom to effect the thumbnail image. I have tried something like this in the click function with no luck.

```
$(this).parents('#slider').closest(".item").children(".vert-flag-mini").show();
```

Comment: What 'button' are you clicking?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. It is an icon, not a button. Here is a demo. You can click on the "heart" icon to toggle the favorites and the separate thumbnail gallery is shown when you click the index icon. http://macosxsupport.com/notebook/

Comment: So it's the `i` element, then? And, for demos, please use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar. That way we can see all the code in action and edit it to make it work.

Comment: It is really just the element with the class .fav or .sticky which in this case is an i element. Sorry about the link, just a bit to complex to put in a jsfiddle easily. I'll work on it.